# Adverb with do + verb

Tags: adverb-position

There is the article 'Practice really does make perfect' at http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/practice-really-does-make-perfect

My question is why adverb is placed before 'does make'? Is 'do make' one word?

Comment: *Does make* -   Emphatic forms,(sometimes called the emphatic tenses or emphatic mood,)
*are made with the auxiliary verb do in the present or past tense + the base form of the verb*:

"he does work very hard."

Comment: @Josh61, this your example 'he does work very hard' isn't so good because in that context 'hard' is always placed after verb. But which one is correct with hardly - 'He hardly does work' or ' He does hardly work'?

Comment: Hardly does not mean *very hard*. The position of *very hard* is just the one shown, *does work very hard*.

Comment: Really is a sentence adverb.

Answer (score 1):

"Do" in that sentence is used as an emphasis.

If we're gonna look at the context you have given (from [University of Cambridge](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/practice-really-does-make-perfect#sthash.Le4SXJkD.dpuf)):

> *New research into the way in which we learn new skills finds that a
>   single skill can be learned faster if its follow-through motion is
>   consistent, but multiple skills can be learned simultaneously if the
>   follow-through motion is varied*.

See, from the way the sentence was phrased, it is implied that it's already common knowledge for a skill to be learned through practice (i.e. consistent follow-through motion). But if you look at the latter part of the sentence, they're adding something else which further proves the first point. They're **emphasizing** that practice makes perfect.

[Here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode119/languagepoint.shtml) is a good resource which talks about "do" as an emphasis.

Comment: So the rule for adverb in such context - adverb + emphasis + 'one-word verb'. Right?